# Error when Updating Database using Stored Procedure

Tags: php, mysql, database, stored-procedures

This is my php code below

```
$token = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
        $complete = 'No';
        $update_sql = "CALL updatetoken ('$db_email','$token','$complete')";
        echo $update_sql;
        // $update_sql = "UPDATE user SET resetToken = {$token}, resetCompleted='No' WHERE email = {$_POST['email']}";
        $sqlfile = mysqli_query($connection, $update_sql);

        if ($sqlfile) {
            echo "Update successful";

        } else {
            echo "Error updating the database";
        }
```

Then the stored procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `updatetoken` (IN `usermail` VARCHAR(100), IN `token` VARCHAR(100), IN `completetask` VARCHAR(100))  UPDATE user SET resetToken = token, resetCompleted = completetask WHERE email = usermail$$
```

[image: IMAGE FOR STORE PROCEDURE]

instead of updating the database, i keep getting error message "Error updating the database", I tried using the normal "INSERT" mysql method from my php code instead of CALL, but still same error message

Comment: Do you have the exact error message?

Comment: Yes,still same error

Answer (score 0):

A semicolon (;) is missing at the end of update sentence:

[image]

Comment: the semi colon is something that even when inserted, is remove automatically by the DBMS...I have try it but it keeps on being remove

Answer (score 0):

```
token = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
$complete = 'No';
$update_sql = "CALL updatetoken ('$db_email','$token','$complete')";
echo $update_sql; 

// $update_sql = "UPDATE user SET resetToken = {$token}, resetCompleted='No' WHERE email = {$_POST['email']}";
$sqlfile = mysqli_query($connection, $update_sql);
if ($sqlfile) { echo "Update successful"; } 
else { echo "Error updating the database";`
```

Comment: from what is above i think your code and my code are similar stuffs, still not working